# How to find the large mod of this large number

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$(836220437623389220135801288562)(143233022103420012) (\mod 83622043762338922013580128856)$

My professor reduced $(836220437623389220135801288562)$ to $2$ and then multiplied $2$ by $(143233022103420012)$ for the final answer.

However, I am not sure how he came to the conclusion that $(836220437623389220135801288562) (\mod 83622043762338922013580128856)$ is congruent to $2$, and that $(143233022103420012)(\mod 83622043762338922013580128856)$ is irreducible.

Is anyone able to explain how was he able to reduce like that just by looking at the number?

Comment: can you imagine a shorter version of the problem, you might see some pattern bvy yourself :)

Comment: Hint: $10 \cdot n + 2 \equiv 2 \pmod n$.

Comment: You've got $ab\bmod c$, where $a$ is $c$ with a 2 stuck on the end, and $b$ is less than $c$. Does that help you? Do you understand how mod works?

Comment: Ah! That makes sense. My problem was I didn't realize that the 836... number is a digit longer than n. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: 14....2 mod 83....856 has to be irreducible because 14......2 < 83......856 (by quite a lot).

Comment: OK, 1861051, now that you understand, let me encourage you to write up and post an answer.